# Is the interpolating Hamiltonian flow of an exact near-identity symplectic map globally defined?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, sg.symplectic-geometry, differential-equations, hamiltonian-mechanics

It is well-known that an analytic near-identity map $\bar{x} = F_{\epsilon}(x) = x + \epsilon f(x) + O(\epsilon^{2})$ may be embedded into the flow of a differential equation, and if that map is symplectic, then the differential equation is of Hamiltonian form - however the Hamiltonian vector field may not be globally defined, even if the mapping is global.

I am interested in what conditions we need to specify for  a globally defined, near-indentity analytic symplectic map to be interpolated by a globally defined Hamiltonian flow. In particular, if this is automatically satisfied for an $\textbf{exact}$ near-identity symplectic map on the standard cylinder $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{S}^1$ ?